# How to add new table inside tr in new line?

Tags: html, css

I have one table:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td (click)="expend()">aaaa</td>  
  <table>
  <tr><td>bbbb</td></tr>
  </table>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now what i want is to add new table for that row so on top i will have that tr and bellow i will have that new table. Any suggestion?

EDIT:

This is my  full table:

```
<table class="custom-table">
                                        <tr dnd-draggable  [dragData]="sa" (onDragStart)="dnd.set(true);" (onDragEnd)="dnd.set(false)"  *ngFor="let sa of customerGeneralInfo?.serviceAccount" (click)="sa?.accountclassCode=='SAGG' ? getSAGG(sa.p_SA_ID):getServiceAccount(sa.p_SA_ID,'CA');addToHistory('CA')">
                                            <td>{{sa?.p_SA_ID}}</td>
                                            <td>{{sa?.address}}</td>
                                            <td *ngIf="sa?.accountclassCode=='SAGG'">{{sa?.accountclassCode}}</td>
                                            <td style="display:block">
                                                <table *ngIf="saggInfo?.serviceAccount?.length > 0">
                                                    <tr *ngFor="let saggsa of saggInfo?.serviceAccount">
                                                        <td>
                                                            {{saggsa?.p_SA_ID}}
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            {{saggsa?.address}}
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>
```

What i want to achive to have this:
aaaaaa -first row
   bbbbb  - second table
ccccc -second row

Comment: How is it not working? Give us a [MCVE]

Comment: its not working because i dont get table in new line

Comment: I don't thing you can put a new table in a `tr`...only a `td`

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td (click)="expend()">aaaa</td>   
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <table>
    <tr><td>bbbb</td></tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it will add at the end of all data from first table and i dont want that

Comment: @None Can you describe exactly what's happening (and why it's bad), so that others will understand your question? Please edit your question instead of scattering comments around that won't be read right away.

Answer (score 0):

Added borders to see where each table begins and ends...

## Edited

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<table class="custom-table">
  <tr dnd-draggable [dragData]="sa" (onDragStart)="dnd.set(true);" (onDragEnd)="dnd.set(false)" *ngFor="let sa of customerGeneralInfo?.serviceAccount" (click)="sa?.accountclassCode=='SAGG' ? getSAGG(sa.p_SA_ID):getServiceAccount(sa.p_SA_ID,'CA');addToHistory('CA')">
    <td>{{sa?.p_SA_ID}}</td>
    <td>{{sa?.address}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="sa?.accountclassCode=='SAGG'">{{sa?.accountclassCode}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <table *ngIf="saggInfo?.serviceAccount?.length > 0">
        <tr *ngFor="let saggsa of saggInfo?.serviceAccount">
          <td>{{saggsa?.p_SA_ID}}</td>
          <td>{{saggsa?.address}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```